# How to remove the first line on the MOTD screen?

Tags: raspbian, ssh, debian

I know how to customize the MOTD screen but I dont know how to remove the first line.
This is what I did:

- `/etc/motd` (customize this file)
- `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`: Change the setting `PrintLastLog` to `no`, this
  will disable the "Last login" message.

But how to remove the first line?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to come from `/run/motd.dynamic` which is generated by `/etc/init.d/motd` during boot.

So you could delete `/run/motd.dynamic` and edit `etc/init.d/motd` to change

```
uname -snrvm > /var/run/motd.dynamic
```

to just

```
/var/run/motd.dynamic
```

Of course if the motd package is updated this change might be overwritten.

Answer (score 1):

1. Edit `/etc/pam.d/login`
2. Comment out (with a # at the beginning of the line) or delete line 85 `#session  optional  pam_exec.so  type=open_session stdout  /bin/uname -snrvm`
3. save and logout
4. login.